# Object #<Object> has no method 'validate' when posting in Express

Tags: json, angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to create a simple poll app with Angular and Express. I've gotten most of it done but the app crashes when POSTing data. The only error the express console seems to be spitting out is:

```
 node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:94
        doc.validate(function (err) {
        ^
```

TypeError: Object # has no method 'validate'

A sample of the data I'm sending would look like:

```
    { 
question: 'string',
  responses:
   { '0': { responseText: 'asdsa' },
     '1': { responseText: 'asdasd' },
     '2': { responseText: 'sadasd' } 
    } 
}
```

Here's my express api:
http://pastebin.com/HT6yp1UN

Here's my model
http://pastebin.com/PJbaRJnX

I think it might have something to do with the mongoose not getting the type of data that it's expecting, but looking at the post request it seems to line up with what my model is expecting. I haven't been able to find much more on this issue, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mongoose schema you defined `responses`to be an array and you are sending across `responses` as an object of objects.

You should shape your data before sending it via POST in order to reflect your mongoose schema:

```
question: 'string',
  responses:
   [ { responseText: 'asdsa' },
     { responseText: 'asdasd' },
     { responseText: 'sadasd' } 
   ] 
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. What a silly mistake, I think I've just been staring at it for too long. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I'll leave this up just in case anyone else runs into similar trouble.